# launching the react application on another machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a novice developer in react. I developed the application on another machine before. Now, trying to start this application  using the "npm install" and "npm start" commands, I get errors like these:

```
App
c:/react_/react-intro/src/App.js:238
  235 |    <Panel>
  236 | <label style={{position:'absolute'}}>
  237 |               Y Axis:
> 238 |               <select value={this.state.y_axis}  onChange={this.handleYaxisChange}>
      | ^  239 |                <option value="Open">Open</option>
  240 |                 <option value="High">High</option>
  241 |                 <option value="Low">Low</option>
View compiled
▶ 16 stack frames were collapsed.
Module../src/index.js
c:/react_/react-intro/src/index.js:7
   4 | import App from './App';
   5 | import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
   8 | 
   9 | // If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
  10 | // unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
View compiled
__webpack_require__
c:/react_/react-intro/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
```

View compiled

Please, help

Comment: Can you list the errors you get when tried running npm start?

Comment: there are no errors in console, only errors in browser, they are in post